# SlimDx и CreateOffscreenPlainSurfaceEx в wine

Tags: linux, directx, wine, slimdx

I'm trying to run application with playing video. My problem is that i'm receive null while:

```
                surface = Surface.CreateOffscreenPlainEx(_device, width, height, useRgb ? Format.X8R8G8B8 : Format.Yuy2, Pool.Default, Usage.None);
```

I'm founded, that the problem is in SlimDX,
`device->InternalPointer->CreateOffscreenPlainSurfaceEx`  returns   D3DERR_INVALIDCALL.
I'm using wine 6.19(staging) with native directx implementation. Can someone suggest any solution or way to find it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem have resolved by changing CreateOffscreenPlainEx to CreateOffscreenPlain.
CreateOffscreenPlainEx or something under it is unimplemented.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).